# Organização de CSS

Tags: css, estilo-de-codificação

Existe um padrão para organizar o CSS?
Por exemplo:

```
.teste{font-family:"arial";font-size:18px;color:white}
```

ou

```
.teste{
font-family:"arial";
font-size:18px;
color:white
}
```

Qual a mais indicada?

Comment: Que eu saiba não existe nenhum padrão. Eu prefiro a segunda opção.

Comment: Como vocês pode afirmar que minha pergunta é baseada em "opiniões", se nem eu sei a forma correta?
Pensei haver um padrão de usabilidade em CSS.

Comment: Se você não sabe, como pode escolher uma resposta correta? Na verdade não existe forma correta, por isto é baseada em opiniões. É questão de gosto. Todo mundo aí não escreveu nenhuma verdade, escreveu qual o gosto deles. É a mesma coisa que perguntar se prefere *tab* ou *spaces*.

Comment: Ué, escolhi a resposta que me pareceu mais convincente e que informou termos que eu não conhecia, assim expandindo a minha pesquisa. Todavia, acho que vocês cometerem um engano. Pensei haver uma forma correta.

Comment: Reabri a pergunta porque existe uma resposta (que é ***não, não existe um padrão***). Porém, seria legal se surgisse uma resposta detalhada explicando as opções existentes, e o porquê de cada uma, sem ser opinativa como as que foram postadas até agora.

Comment: @FelipeStoker E o fechamento foi justamente para indicar que você estava enganado. Ele indicou que as respostas estavam baseadas em opiniões. Lembrando que fechamento não é punição, inclusive discordo do negativo que a pergunta recebeu, ela é útil, só que ela suscita opiniões. Talvez até algumas respostas mereçam negativos por serem pura opinião, não ajudar de fato a responder, mas eu não chegaria neste ponto, tanto que n]ao negativei nenhuma também. Agora tem uma resposta que realmente responde bem (nem quis melhorar a minha depois que ela surgiu). Espero que troque o *accept*.

Comment: Obrigado pela compreensão pessoal. À partir das respostas, já estudei uma nova forma de prosseguir com meus próximos projetos.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Não existe uma regra estabelecida para a forma como os arquivos de CSS são indentados e/ou formatados. Cada programador tem o seu estilo o que torna as coisas difíceis quando falamos em padronizar.

Contudo, existe um consenso de que os mesmos devem ser facilmente interpretados pelo programador, ao mesmo tempo que devem estar otimizados para o melhor desempenho da página web onde são utilizados.

## O melhor dos dois mundos

A coexistência destes dois ideais pode ser atingida da seguinte forma:

### CSS

Arquivo de CSS devidamente indentado e comentado:

```css
/* Lines
 * ------------------------------ */
.line-service{
    background-color:#A9A9A9;
    height:1px;
    width:240px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:60px;
}
.diagonal-left{
    left:-214px;
    transform:rotate(142deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(142deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(142deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(142deg);
}
.diagonal-right{
    right:-214px;
    transform:rotate(38deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(38deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(38deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(38deg);
}
.vertical-center{
    height:168px;
    width:1px;
    left:50%;
    bottom:-13px;
}
```

### PHP

Para efeitos de exemplificação, vou utilizar código em PHP de forma a servir o CSS para um website:

```php
<?php
header('Content-type: text/css');

// define o buffer para a função "compress"
ob_start("compress");

function compress($buffer) {

    /* remove comentários */
    $buffer = preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $buffer);

    /* remove tabs, spaces, newlines, etc. */
    $buffer = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t", '  ', '    ', '    '), '', $buffer);

    return $buffer;
}

$cssFiles = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/*.css';

foreach(glob($cssFiles) as $file) {

    include($file);
}

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

A ideia é ter os arquivos "normalmente", ou seja, da forma com que mais nos relacionamos para os ler.

A linguagem que está a servir o website para o navegador é quem fica encarregue de otimizar o ficheiro e servir o mesmo o mais otimizado possível.

Com o código de PHP em cima apresentado o ficheiro é servido da seguinte forma:

```css
.line-service{background-color:#A9A9A9;height:1px;width:240px;position:absolute;bottom:60px;}.diagonal-left{left:-214px;transform:rotate(142deg);-moz-transform:rotate(142deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(142deg);-o-transform:rotate(142deg);}.diagonal-right{right:-214px;transform:rotate(38deg);-moz-transform:rotate(38deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(38deg);-o-transform:rotate(38deg);}.vertical-center{height:168px;width:1px;left:50%;bottom:-13px;}
```

Tal e qual como pretendemos, sem espaços, sem tabulações, sem comentários...

### Como utilizar (HTML):

Para o exemplo prático, o ficheiro `css.php` que contém o código PHP em cima apresentado está dentro da pasta onde estão todos os ficheiros CSS que pretendemos servir ao website.

No HTML, ao invés de chamarmos cada um dos ficheiros de CSS, chamamos apenas o ficheiro PHP, ficando o mesmo responsável por ler todos os CSSs e enviar os mesmos devidamente otimizados:

```html
<link href="http://www.meusite.com/caminho/para/css.php" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

## Vantagens

- Ficheiros de CSS sempre legíveis e formatados como pretendemos;
- Markup de HTML reduzida pois uma só linha fornece ao website todo o CSS;
- CSS otimizado e compactado para poupar o máximo de espaço possível;
- Sistema mais fácil de manter no futuro sem precisarmos de recorrer a ferramentas de terceiros para compactar e descompactar o nosso código.

Comment: Resposta perfeita. Obrigado pela colaboração.

Answer (score 10):

**Não, não há um padrão.**

O que deve ser considerado é: por exemplo, na hora do desenvolvimento, muitos autores preferem deixar tudo separado para facilitar a localização das partes de interesse para manutenção, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
div {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   font-family: arial;
   color: red;
   line-spacing: 20px;
}
```

Outros preferem separar linhas por assuntos, como no exemplo abaixo (posicao, aparencia, etc):

```
div {
   position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;
   font-family: arial; color: red;
   line-spacing: 20px;
}
```

Se a pessoa tem uma consciência do que está fazendo, nada impede de deixar tudo em uma linha só, ou usar misto:

```
body,html { margin:0; padding:0 }

div {
   position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;
   font-family: arial; color: red; line-spacing: 20px;
}
```

ou seja, é **questão de gosto pessoal**, ou **padrão para trabalho em equipe**, ou **política da empresa**, isso se for o caso.

**Por outro lado,** existem os processadores de CSS que compactam o código, o que pode se traduzir em uma imensa economia de dinheiro, dada a menor banda que você precisa utilizar ao evitar transporte desnecessário de espaços, quebras de linha e tabulações. Pode parecer bobeira quando o site serve meia dúzia de páginas por dia, mas imagine o CSS de grandes sites, como sistemas de busca e redes sociais.

Vale lembrar que muitas vezes **compensa testar** se a minificação do CSS é realmente vantajosa, pois em muitas ocasiões basta configurar o servidor (seja Apache, NGINX, IIS, etc) a usar GZIP, o que já reduz o código imensamente, muitas vezes valendo mais a pena do que processamento extra sobre o CSS (a não ser que você faça algum cache local do resultado).

Answer (score 3):

Concordo com o Jorge B., ao meu ver, é questão de preferência.
Creio que faça diferença quando a quantidade de **CSS** customizado é grande e está no mesmo arquivo que o código da página(o que não acho muito recomendado, e sim um arquivo à parte), pois pode gerar uma maior dificuldade para localizar/navegar o conteúdo como um todo.

Answer (score 3):

Não existe um padrão. As duas formas são questão de gosto. De acordo com minha percepção a segunda é preferida pela maioria porque parece mais limpo, mais legível. Alguns acham que a primeira deixa o código mais curto. Mas tudo isto é questionável, é questão de gosto.

Pronto. É só isto.

Answer (score 2):

Na verdade quando eu termino de desenvolver o `CSS`, eu faço uma compactação do arquivo `CSS` para fins de otimização do site ou sistema ou o que quer que seja. Para tal uso este **[site](http://cssminifier.com)**, de passagem uma ferramenta excelente para compressão de folhas de estilo.

Comment: Se você tiver que abrir esse CSS depois, como você vai entender um código minificado?

Comment: Este site **http://cssbeautify.com** permite remontar a minha folha de estilo completo lhe dando um padrão otimizado das regras e é assim que eu trabalho.

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade, ao contrário do que as outras respostas informaram, **existe sim** um padrão, estabelecido pelo Google, que você encontra no [Google Style Guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml#CSS_Formatting_Rules).

Lá você encontrará, entre outras regras, a seguinte:

> ### Selector and Declaration Separation
>
> Separate selectors and declarations by new lines.
>
> Always start a new line for each selector and declaration.
>
> ```
> /* Not recommended */
> a:focus, a:active {
>   position: relative; top: 1px;
> }
> /* Recommended */
> h1,
> h2,
> h3 {
>   font-weight: normal;
>   line-height: 1.2;
> }
> ```

Ou seja, **é sim** recomendado separar seletores e declarações por quebra de linha.

Answer (score 0):

Gosto de organizar meu css com pre-processadores, eu utilizo o `SASS` http://sass-lang.com, também utilizo uma metodologia chamada de SMACSS https://smacss.com/ onde ensina como fazer uma arquitetura de css modular.

Answer (score 0):

A segunda opção é a "mais legível", porém ambas funcionam do mesmo jeito. Trata-se apenas de identação (a segunda opção esta identada e a primeira não).

Answer (score 0):

Eu quando programo em CSS utilizo sempre uma syntax diferente pelo facto de ter melhor conhecimento do código e fácil acesso.

```
.menu
{
   color: #FFF;
   text-align: left;
}
```

É mais fácil aceder ao código caso haja alguma falha por exemplo alterar a cor.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize da segunda forma enquanto estiver produzindo o código, por conta da **Indentação** se torna mais fácil de se entender, ao terminar a produção do mesmo, utilize um **"CSS Minifier"** que fará com que o código fique mais ou menos igual a primeira forma, fazendo com que o arquivo fique menor.